# Keep HashMap data while app is running - Android

Tags: java, android, hashmap, data-storage

I have a HashMap which contains data that is relevant to a specific Activity.
The data should be fetched from a server and is quite big so I dont want to fetch it inside that certain Activity. Instead, I am fetching all the data in the main activity, into a custom class and then I create a HashMap for holding all of the objects and save it in my Application class.

When the user goes into the other activity, the data is ready to go without any need to wait, by calling the HashMap I created earlier from the Application class.

It is all working fine except some times when the app is in the background for a long time, the data stored in the HashMap is being initialize by Android.

I've read that storing objects in the Apllication class is bad and I wont be able to avoid this error, so my question is what is the right approach for doing that proccess?
I need a solution that will keep my HashMap object alive as long as there's an instance of my app.

Comment: You need to maintain serialised catch to hold data for long time.

Answer (score 2):

```
I have a HashMap which contains data that is relevant to a specific Activity.
```

If this is the case, why wouldn't you want to keep the `HashMap` as an instance variable in your activity?  Storing data for a specific `Activity` in your `Application` object isn't good object-oriented design.

If you need to keep the data in the `HashMap` when the `Activity` is destroyed and created, you can save it in `onSaveInstanceState()`.

Comment: Instance variable option: 

What if the user didn't navigate to that Activity when he first opened the app, and after a day or two, while the app is in the background, he wants to enter that Activity? Does the data will still be there?


onSaveInstanceState() option:

My HashMap is containing custom class objects, how can i save it in a Bundle?

Comment: If the activity has been destroyed (i.e. back button pressed or app quit), you can save it in onSaveInstanceState().  If it's only been paused (i.e. home button pressed) it'll still be in memory.  You can store custom objects in a bundle with putSerializable() if they implement the Serializable interface.

Comment: What if I'll create an instance of the Application class on every Activity? Would it keep it from being destroyed?

Comment: Application is supposed to be a singleton -- don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

One of the available approaches is to use a "headless" retained `Fragment` to persist the `HashMap` data across `Activity` recreation. According to [android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29) such `Fragment`'s lifecycle is quite different:

- **onDestroy()** will not be called (but onDetach() still will be, because the fragment is being detached from its current activity).
- **onCreate**(Bundle) will not be called since the fragment is not being re-created.
- **onAttach**(Activity) and onActivityCreated(Bundle) will still be called.

Thus, when your `Activity` dies from a configuration change and so on, your `Fragment` does not. When `Activity` is recreated, it could request your retained `Fragment` for a piece of "cached" data. [Read this](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html), if you like to do it this way.

The other approach I could think of is to cache your data in a database or a file, but that would be an overkill, I guess.

Comment: Switching my app from Activity to Fragments will be like write it all over again, and I would prefer to avoid it.

Using database will be very complex since I use custom class objects

Comment: You don't have to rewrite it whole. The retained headless Fragment does not have to display anything at all. Basically, it could be like an invisible container that survives the Activity and keeps the data while your Application is not destroyed at all (while your Activity could, and many times).

Answer (score 0):

> The data should be fetched from a server and is quite big so I dont
>   want to fetch it inside that certain Activity.

Mb better to use Sqlite for data storage purposes because android devices doesnt have unlimited resoureces?